# electron-forge: Supposedly missing dependencies of git and node but both appear in package.json

Tags: node.js, git, electron, electron-forge

I put in the terminal: `electron-forge import`, and I get this message:

> It looks like you are missing some dependencies you need to get Electron running.
>   Make sure you have git installed and Node.js version 6.0.0+

But this is my package.json:

`{
  "name": "memoryassitant-electron",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "software para estudiantes  de asistencia en procesos de memorización de información diversa",
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "electron-forge": "^5.2.4",
    "git": "^0.1.5",
    "node": "^14.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "^8.2.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "test",
    "dev": "electron index.js",
    "test1": "electron frontend.html",
    "installer1": "electron-forge import"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "memory",
    "learning",
    "asistant"
  ],
  "author": "Guillermo Baldán",
  "license": "ISC"
}`

As you can see I have git (^0.1.5) and node (^14.0.0) supposedly installed. I don´t understand why I get this error.

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved in the comments of this question:
**[Error Message: It looks like you are missing some dependencies you need to get Electron running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61408966/error-message-it-looks-like-you-are-missing-some-dependencies-you-need-to-get-e?noredirect=1#comment108636469_61408966)**