# Error Message: It looks like you are missing some dependencies you need to get Electron running

Tags: node.js, git, electron, electron-forge

After globally installing electron-forge with `npm install -g electron-forge` any command I enter in the terminal related to electron-forge gives me the following message:

> It seems like it's missing some dependencies you need to run Electron.
>   Make sure you have git and Node.js version 6.0.0+ installed

I don't know why it tells me that it is missing git and Node which both installed both locally and globally versions 0.1.5 and 14.0.0 respectively.

Comment: [`git` 0.1.5](https://www.npmjs.com/package/git) requires [native git command line](https://git-scm.com/).

Comment: @phd: your comment helped me a lot I installed git again,
But this time I chose to install the CLI, please edit an answer and I will validate it in order to close this  question with an answer.
If you don't I guess I'll have to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[git 0.1.5](https://www.npmjs.com/package/git) is a partial implementation of access to git object database; for other not implemented things it requires [native git command line](https://git-scm.com/).

Comment: Install git from here: https://git-scm.com/downloads, make sure it adds to PATH, then restart the Windows Terminal/Command Prompt.

Answer (score 1):

If you are still facing this error after installing GIT and Nodejs, for some reason electron also requires yarn installed globally. You can install it by using

```
npm i -g yarn
```